# What's the difference between queries?

Tags: sql

Here's the dataset:

> Movie (mID, title, year, director) English: There is a movie with ID
>   number mID, a title, a release year, and a director.
>
> Reviewer (rID, name) English: The reviewer with ID number rID has a
>   certain name.
>
> Rating (rID, mID, stars, ratingDate) English: The reviewer rID gave
>   the movie mID a number of stars rating (1-5) on a certain ratingDate.

Here's the question: Find the titles of all movies that have no ratings.

My answer: (returns an empty set)

```
select title from movie,rating where movie.mid=rating.mid and stars is null
```

Correct answer:

```
 select title
 from movie 
 left join rating using (mID)
 where stars is null
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with my join? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have another bash at the question so anybody has a hope of understanding it. As to the problem with your join, are you missing the t - aka joint?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do a full cross join between movie and rating. This means your result set initially contains all possible (movie, rating) combinations.

You require `movie.mid = rating.mid`. This will limit your result set to only those (movie, rating) pairs where the rating actually is for the movie it is paired with.

But imagine a movie without a rating. It never occurs in the rating table, so `movie.mid = rating.mid` will also never be true. Since this is never true, all movies without a rating will be stripped from the result set by that where clause.

The correct answer uses a `left join`. A join matches all rows in movie with all rows in ratings that pass the join condition (in this case `mID` needs to be equal). So far this is semantically the same as what you wrote. But then the `left` part comes into play: it means that for any movie row where there isn't *any* row in ratings that passes the join condition, the movie row is included anyway (once) with all `NULL` values for the rating table columns. The `stars is null` condition then takes only rows generated by the `left` effect. (Note that the where clause will only work correctly if `stars` is not allowed to be null in the ratings table.)

Answer (score 0):

If a movie has no ratings, `rating.mid` will be null, so `movie.mid=rating.mid` will be false.

If a movie does have ratings, then `movie.mid=rating.mid` will work, but (presumably) `stars is null` will be false.

So your condition is never satisfied.

The correct answer that you posted works because the `join` condition is separate to the `where` condition. First the `movies` table is joined to the `rating` table, then the result is filtered to rows which had nothing joined to them.